# Run Condition Plugin add boolean expression

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have String build parameter "someString".
I have step that I want to execute iff `${someString} == "123"` 
I don't understand from plugin [page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin) what I need to write in expression  text box.
Can someone clarify it?